# How can you push every n amount of items into a new array in php

Tags: php, arrays

lets say there is an array like this `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`. How can add every 7 values into a new array that looks like this `[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrays will be equally sized (your example has 7 values in the first array and six in the second - not sure if it's a typo or not) then you can do this:

```
$array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

$chunkedArrays = array_chunk($array, 7);

print_r($chunkedArrays);
```

`array_chunk` documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: You've been faster than me, kudos to you :)

Comment: ah yes it was a typo, supposed to be 7 values in the first two and then the remaining in the last one, thanks!

Comment: @Cid ha - sorry, it's not often I am the fastest when answering a question on SO!